# Comparing (near) future date to current date, how to

Tags: php, datetime, date

check whether the the future date is in the same month as current one? I tried...

```
$Current_Date=time(); // today - 31st July
$Future_Date =mkdate(~1st aug~); // tomorrow - 1st Aug
if(("m",$Future_Date )>date("m",$Current_Date ))
    echo date("j",$Current_Date ) . "SAME MONTH!!";
else
    echo date("j",$Current_Date ) . date("m",$Current_Date );
```

But say if `$Future_Date`~1st July Next year, it still shows "SAME MONTH".

I'm making kind of a countdown thing which counts how many months left till the `$Future_Date`. I wanted to display just the date if it's in the same month, but date with its month if it's in the next or any later month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dateinterval class in PHP for this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php or you can also compare on year as well:

```
if(("m",$Future_Date )==date("m",$Current_Date ) && ("Y",$Future_Date )==date("Y",$Current_Date ))
    echo date("j",$Current_Date ) . "SAME MONTH!!";
else
    echo date("j",$Current_Date ) . date("m",$Current_Date );
```

Comment: `dateinterval` is perfect. I hadn't known of it. I have quite a few thhings depending on `mkdate()`'s input format. Is there a way to add hours too into this declaration: `$Future = new DateTime('2010-01-01');` edit:just hours.